# Editing (and creating) seemingly useless tags

Tags: support, tagging, specific-user, tag-wikis

In the past few days I have noticed a certain user editing tag information for freshly created tags that seem completely useless, for example [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1566584/revisions). This seems like a case of badge-hunting to me. Unfortunately I was unable to find a way to report this to a moderator. Should I do so? And if so, how to do so (without asking a question on Meta)?

I also mention *creating* useless tags in the question title because I suspect the aforementioned user is also creating many useless tags, though I don't know how I can see who is creating these tags.

Comment: Since the tag will probably removed, a more permanent link would be link to the [revision history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1566584/revisions) or to the [suggested edit review](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/540080). The link you provided is a bit confusing since it only show the empty tag-excerpt. You could have linked to [tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/summand/info) - this at least shows something. (Until the tag is removed.).

Comment: BTW your title mentions creating tags, but in the body of your post you only discuss tag-info (=tag-excerpt + tag-wiki|.

Comment: [Another example.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1565067) The user thought their question was worthy of three whole new tags...! (Including two extremely similar ones.)

Comment: [And another example.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1566703)

Comment: @Servaes I have now read all the information in your comments below my answer and I can now appreciate your point of view. I can see now that too many tags is a bad thing as it can lead to a restriction on the amount of attention a post receives; this is especially the case when the tags are _too_ specific (like the ones I was creating). But before you explained that to me I thought that it was better to have _more_ tags in order to break the areas of mathematics up into very particular topics so that users can find exactly what they are looking for.....

Comment: @Servaes So if there is one thing this thread has taught me is that new tags should only be created if there is a very strong likelihood that they will be used often enough by other users. Since I am not very good at making a distinction between a tag that is likely to be used frequently and one that will not; I will therefore not create any-more new tags. As for the ones I have already created; according to one of your links it will be erased after 6 months since no one else is likely to use it. Or, if you like I can delete all the tags I have created? I do have one more question for you.....

Comment: @Servaes Should I delete the answer I posted in this thread? The reason I ask is because if I understood your post correctly, you were looking for an answer for 'How to report user: BLAZE (myself) for creating seemingly useless tags?'. My answer clearly does not address that question so I was going to delete it. But if I do so all the comments you placed below it will be lost, and some of them raise very good points and made me think twice. Anyway, I apologize to yourself and Najib, and promise that there will be no more new tags from BLAZE. Thanks for taking the time to explain this to me.

Answer (score 2):

The Meta site is always there for you to discuss your problems with the mods and the developers. This is perhaps the best way to bring your problems and queries in everyone's notice.

You can ask them to a chat and tell them personally what you want to tell them or what instructions you need to give him. But that also requires both of you to be in chat together which might not always be possible.

In that case, you can obviously chat with a moderator of that site on chat for one of them is always available and there you can bring up your issue.

As for whether you should have reported this to a moderator or not, I want to quote the lines on the review page of Stack exchange:

[image]

So whatever you think is best for helping yourself as well as others, you are welcome to do that and if you are wrong, there are others who are always there to correct you.